# OLE Object attachment on Excel Worksheet - Icon label displaying as random alphanumeric string

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ole

I'm automating Excel through Microsoft Access to create a report.  This report requires some approval attachments to be embedded. The code I am using is (in Access):

```
    If fso.FileExists(strPath) Then
        xlDoc.Sheets(TEMPLATE_WORKSHEET_NAME).OLEObjects.Add _
            Filename:=strPath, _
            Link:=False, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
            IconIndex:=0, _
            IconLabel:=GetFileNameFromPath(strAttachment)
    End If
```

Where `strPath` is the full path of the file (the `GetfileNameFromPath()` function just returns the file name correctly, I've checked).

However when I open the Excel spreadsheet, the file has been attached with an alphanumeric string as the label like this:

[image: Random filename]

The string seems to be random and is always different when the document is generated even if the attachment is the same. The extension is correct.

The online resources for adding OLE Attachments to Excel documents are very sketchy so I'm having trouble finding proper documentation and I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The random name comes from the temporary copy of the picture in your appdata/local/temp folder. 
Even if you specify a different icon and provide it via IconFileName - Property, as soon as you save the workbook, excel will replace the icon with the default picture/filetype icon(even the custom label will be reset to the picture filename).

if you want to test it yourself, here is some code where i set the Icon to the Notepad++ Icon:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add _
Filename:="XYZ.png", _
Link:=False, _
DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
IconIndex:=0, _
IconFileName:="..\Notepad++Portable\App\AppInfo\appicon.ico", _
IconLabel:="blablabla"
```

As long as you don't save the workbook the icon will be displayed with the custom Label and Icon, after save it will be back to default again.